# Jquery cycle - nested ul li ul li multiple images (different amount) in each list

Tags: jquery

got a problem, can't get my head around this jquery and would appreciate your help/guidance.

Function I need:

Each menu list contains images that should scroll through when clicked & scroll though when mouse over. If mouse hover it will scroll through the images in set interval time limit.

Once I make it scroll then i'll seek for further functionality but would appreciate if it could at least work at this moment

Ultimate function: to also stop animation when mouseout maybe include more efficient coding using .wrap and perhaps pausing the image when mouseover image div.

Here is the Jquery I wrote which doesn't work btw.

```
    $(function() {
    $('.main-img ul').cycle({
        fx: 'fadeout',
        height:      458,
        speed:       300,
        timeout:     0,
        pager:'.menu ul li',
        pagerEvent: 'click',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
            return '.menu ul li:eq(' + idx + ') a'; 
        },
        after: function(){
            // start new sub animaion
        },
        before: function(){
            // stop the current animation
        }

    });
});/*
```

and here is the html

```
        <div class="main-cont">
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="portfolio"><span>Portfolio</span></div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="camp-txt"><span>One</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="edit-txt"><span>Two</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="ad-txt"><span>Three</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="bio-txt"><span>Four</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="vid-txt"><span>Five</span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="footer"><span>Footer</span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="main-img">
            <ul>
                <li><ul>
                    <li><img src="images/port/1.jpg" width="597" height="453" alt="img"  /></li>
                    <li><img src="images/port/2.jpg" width="597" height="453" alt="img"  /></li>
                    <li><img src="images/port/3.jpg" width="597" height="453" alt="img"  /></li>
                </ul></li>
                <li><ul>
                    <li><img src="images/port/4.jpg" width="597" height="453" alt="img"  /></li>
                    <li><img src="images/port/5.jpg" width="597" height="453" alt="img"  /></li>
                    <li><img src="images/port/6.jpg" width="597" height="453" alt="img"  /></li>
                </ul></li>
                <li><ul>
                    <li><img src="images/port/7.jpg" width="597" height="453" alt="img"  /></li>
                    <li><img src="images/port/8.jpg" width="597" height="453" alt="img"  /></li>
                </ul></li>
                <li><ul>
                    <li><img src="images/port/9.jpg" width="597" height="453" alt="img"  /></li>
                    <li><img src="images/port/10.jpg" width="597" height="453" alt="img"  /></li>
                </ul></li>
               <li><ul>
                    <li><img src="images/port/11.jpg" width="597" height="453" alt="img"  /></li>
                    <li><img src="images/port/12.jpg" width="597" height="453" alt="img"  /></li>
                </ul></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: you want 5 slideshows all visible or only one at a time based on hover?

Comment: 1 slideshow that will show all slides. Image 1, 2 and 3 will be shown when mouse hover over menu UL LI number 1 for example. Also if possible to cycle through 1, 2, 3 when click on menu UL LI number 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting all of the sub UL's displayed, and menu hover to trigger pause/resume of applicable slideshow try this:

DEMO :  http://jsfiddle.net/Gq8uu/2/

```
/* set options for all slideshows */
var cycleOpts={
   timeout: 2000,
    manualTrump:true    
}

$(function() {
    var $menu_items = $('.menu li');
    var $shows = $('.main-img li ul')

    $shows.each(function(idx) {
        var $sho = $(this);
        /* create slidshow and set to pause*/
        $sho.cycle(cycleOpts).cycle('pause');
        /* menu hover pause/resume show*/
        $menu_items.eq(idx).on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(evt) {
            var action = evt.type == 'mouseenter' ? 'resume' : 'pause';
            $sho.toggleClass('active').cycle(action);
        /* menu click for next slide*/  
        }).click(function(){
            $sho.cycle('next');
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your post.

I do not want all the sub ul's displayed though. There will be one main div, 5 menu ULs and multiple images for each menu UL.

Scrolling over 1 in the menu UL for example will trigger a hover and the images in the first UL group will cycle through.

Clicking 1 in the menu will also cycle in images (if possible).

Mouse off should stop the cycle to avoid multiple cycles at the same time.

If there is anything I can do to help you help me please let me know.

Thanks you very much for your time and help!

Comment: this version is likely more inline with what you want. The trick is the extremely wide slideshow_wrap element so all the slidshows are not hidden when cycle gets called and it can set proper widths  http://jsfiddle.net/Gq8uu/4/

Comment: thank you again! That is exactly what I was after Thanks!...I hope I have repped you correctly.

Comment: Hey Again, I need an amendment made, I tried to do it by myself with no success. Basically I need a Li in the menu that will bring up 1 image that won't slide...I tried returning null basically. Also there is a problem with adding just one image to a slide show..What do you recommend? (if you can help out obviously.)